# attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently making a script so that when a block is touched, the player will go to position. It is

> game.Workspace.AUPortal.Glitch4.Position

and me need help in this error.

> Workspace.A12.MovePlayer:4: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'

Script:

```
function onTouched(hit)
    local h = hit.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    local playerMod = require(game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerModule"))
    local controls = playerMod:GetControls()
    if h~=nil then
        controls:Disable()
        pos = game.Workspace.AUPortal.Glitch4.Position 
        h:MoveTo(pos)
        wait()
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume you are trying to access the **LocalPlayer** inside of a standard **Script** which is something you cannot do.

You can only access the **LocalPlayer** inside of a **LocalScript**, hence why you're getting an error for the WaitForChild. Because the **LocalPlayer** does not exist (it's nil).

With the **Touched** event you can get actually get a reference to the player you're trying use:

```lua
Part.Touched:Connect(function(HitPart)
 local Humanoid = HitPart.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid');
 if (Humanoid) then
  local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(HitPart.Parent);
  -- You can then use this player reference.
 end
end)
```

Comment: I agree, that LocalPlayer = nill. But. I solved the problem with only null value. Now this local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(HitPart.Parent) write me error about: GetControls is not a valid member of Player "Players.DanilX448" (This function doesn't exist)

Comment: GetControls is a clientside function. You would need to do this in a LocalScript or use a RemoteEvent, alternatively you could just anchor the Humanoid for the short period of time that you don't want them to move.